# PHP Memory Exhausted Even I'm Sure That I Have More

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

A beautifully running script of my own started to give error :

PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 12582912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 78 bytes)

and i'm pretty sure that my memory limit is not 12 MB. Also this is not related to script since i know i can run it on my localhost. It needs 17MB of memory as Codeigniter Profiler says.

So what can be the cause of this ? Why my server thinks it has 12MB memory limit...

Comment: I think your script is not that 'beautifully' as you say.

Comment: I'm quite sure something sets your memory limit to 12MB. Examine phpinfo() output & webserver configuration.

Comment: What makes you think you php memory limit it higher than 12MB?

Comment: @Daan sorry but you are wrong. It was beautiful enough to work for 3 months without any problem.

Comment: @Wrikken here http://www.adresegel.com/info.php I couldn't see anything like that

Comment: @Steve because i look to phpinfo(), and i also ask to my service provider if there's anything wrong with server.

Comment: If it's NOT in a vanilla phpinfo(), but you DO run into it in a script... then logically that script does something with the limit. Find that location in the script.

Comment: @Wrikken thanks. What do you mean by 'vanilla' ?

Comment: @Wrikken also i'm damn sure that there's no change in script for a few weeks. It started to do it today. What can cause it? A newly added file or something?

Comment: Well, a VCS (SVN, git, etc. al) would normally tell you...

Answer (score 1):

You could try using ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M'); in your php code.

It is not recommended to set it that high, but you can lower it later once you find the real reason.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

You can then use this function: memory_get_usage() to check how much memory your application is using at a specific row. Use it to find a specific row where the leak is.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php

Answer (score 0):

You can increase memory like this:

```
 ini_set('memory_limit','256M');
```

Comment: I tried that one but i still get [Mon Sep 15 16:53:02 2014] [error] [client 78.179.146.185] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 12582912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in

Comment: Please think about that it still shows 12582912 bytes

Answer (score 0):

Just because your server has more memory doesn't mean it will or should allocate it all to one particularly greedy scripting system (otherwise one coding error could chew up all the resources of the system).
Therefore PHP imposes its own limit on how much it's allowed to take. If you modify your htaccess file, adding:

```
 php_value memory_limit 20M
```

should allow it to take up to 20Mb. Obviously, you can play around with this to see how much you need (try lowering it first and see if the number changes in that error case).

You can find out more about memory_limit at the [PHP.net site](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit)

Note that you should really try and reduce the amount of memory your script needs (because other systems on the server will now get less), but this solution will at least get you where you're going.

And as others have said, you can also use ini_set to set the same variable at the start of that specific script, and it will then revert to the standard at the end of the running. Note however that (for obvious reasons), some servers don't allow their scripts to just say "I need all the resources for my Srz Bzns" and starve the rest of the server.

Comment: I know that php_value stuff but it doesn't work on my situation. I tried it and I also know that there's no restriction about my memory_limit.

Comment: @dreamend Interesting, because according to that error there *must* be.

Comment: ok. So lets check it again. Can you please send me what must be included in .htaccess ?    Also my script is not on the root folder. (There's a magento installation there and that has a .htaccess too)  I don't know this information is needed but does my root .htaccess effects the other .htaccess that will be in the script folder ?